# Mysql error in syntax at 'Ctrl-C' line 1 restoring MysqlDump

Tags: linux, mysql

I'm using linux and i've tried both

`mysql -u root -pabc123 < ~/Desktop/restore.sql`

and while logged in as root to mysql

`\. ~/Desktop/restore.sql`

I keep getting the error `You have an error in your SQl syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MYSQL server version for the right syntan to use near 'Ctrl-C' at line 1`

this is driving me bananas, does anybody have any idea why?

This is a mysqldump --all-databases file

Thanks!

here is the first few lines

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.1.58, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: 
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.1.58-1ubuntu1

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Current Database: `mytmpDB`
--

CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `
```

Comment: What does the first line or two look like?

Comment: Sounds like your dump file is not really a dump file. Have you opened it up in a text editor to see?

Comment: `cat -e ~/Desktop/restore.sql` may show up control characters which you'll need to remove

Comment: @KCD can you give me the entire command i tried exactly what you typed and it just cave me back Ctrl-C -- exit!$

Comment: @KCD i just chop out all of the top command line and it took it

Comment: So the reason this happened for me was that I accidentally flipped the < > pointer. `mysql -u root -pabc123 > ~/Desktop/file.sql`

That ran for awhile doing nothing, so I killed it with Ctrl-C.

It wrote the `Ctrl-C -- exit!$` to the file, thus replacing all of the sql that had been in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mysql -u root -pabc123 < sed -e 's/^C//g' ~/Desktop/restore.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to change your login user?

maybe the user when you create database is not the same as the user you backup your database ?

I have the same problem too.

you can try

> sudo -u username -i

and do the same operation ， Good Luck!

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem too.
When I changed a command mysqldump

> mysqldump -u root db_name

to

> mysqldump -u root db_name > db_name.sql

it works at restoreing mysqldump.